# Magento 2.2.2 wysiwyg upload images broken in admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have tried to upload image in block using wysiwyg editor.

1.click the Insert/Edit image
2.choose a image
3.save

but image not showing in preview.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, one extension disabled after this it's showing fine